# Google maps how far postcode is from fixed location Ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I've been looking around and am unable to find any information on how to implement google maps into my rails application.

What I want to achieve is a page where the the map is shown on the screen with a fixed marker location of a shop. The user is able to type in their postcode and the map shows the distance between the two locations.

Could I please get some help with this :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This kind of question is a bit open-ended and a bit too broad for a good fit for Stack Overflow. here we prefer questions that have a single, "right" answer - they're solvable and can be helpful to other people that might have the same problem. What you're asking for is really help from a mentor - perhaps you could look for a mentor at your local ruby-users group, or search for websites that offer them?

Comment: Alternatively have a go at solving it yourself - do all the bits that you know how to do... have a stab at all the bits you're a little unsure of but can look up... google any error messages you get and try to fix any bugs that way... and if you're still stuck on something, come back and ask here by showing the code you've written and the error message you are getting. We can totally help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a gem for that

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Or just insert it into script tags onto your page

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial